# Access two rows based on one columns but also access other columns for those rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns weight,height,knee,date,id I wanted to find two rows in the same table- the first row is min(weight) and the other is max(weight). How do I also access the dates and ids for these two rows even though everything is in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the min and max weight:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    weight = (SELECT MIN(weight) FROM yourTable) OR
    weight = (SELECT MAX(weight) FROM yourTable);
```

Note that if there be more than one record tied for the min/max weight, then the above query could yield more than 2 records.  If ties are a possibility, then you should provide logic for how to handle this.

If you are using MySQL 8 or later, and have access to `ROW_NUMBER`, then there is a slick solution here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY weight) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY weight DESC) rn2
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE 1 IN (rn1, rn2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`union all` comes to mind:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 order by weight asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 order by weight desc
 limit 1
);
```

This should be pretty optimal in terms of performance if you have an index on `weight`.

This guarantees exactly two rows in the result set, even if there are ties.